# Transposing/pivoting rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

There are many questions available, and I explored several such questions in SO, but none helped.

In question - `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns/56670844#56670844`
In step -3  - They have itemvalue (mine meta_value) as int, but in my case these are varchar, so I cannot really use the sum function.

Database: MySQL

My raw data

```
umeta_id    user_id meta_key    meta_value
    1   1   nickname    kp
    2   1   first_name  Kumar
    3   1   last_name   Prasad
    4   1   description hello
    5   2   nickname    rg
    6   2   first_name  raghav
    7   2   last_name   gupta
    8   2   description welcome
```

My required selected data

```
user_id   nickname  first_name last_name   description
1         kp        kumar      prasad      hello
2         rg        raghav     gupta       welcome
```

My unsuccessful attempt as follows:

```
SELECT user_id, 
case when meta_key='nickname' then meta_value else null end as nickname,
case when meta_key='first_name' then meta_value else null end as first_name,
case when meta_key='last_name' then meta_value else null end as last_name,
case when meta_key='description' then meta_value else null end as description
from user_table GROUP BY user_id;

user_id nickname    first_name  last_name   description
1   kp [NULL]   [NULL]  [NULL]
2   rg  [NULL]  [NULL]  [NULL]
```

Comment: Before you wrote that the duplicate does not helpyou, please read step 3 and the considerations sections in the accrpted answer carefully!

Comment: In step 3 - create view history_itemvalue_pivot as (
  select
    hostid,
    sum(A) as A,
    sum(B) as B,
    sum(C) as C
  from history_extended
  group by hostid
);

select * from history_itemvalue_pivot;

+--------+------+------+------+
| hostid | A    | B    | C    |
+--------+------+------+------+
|      1 |   10 |    3 | NULL |
|      2 |    9 | NULL |   40 |
+--------+------+------+------+

That question's itemvalue are integers and hence he did the sum. But in my case it is string/varchar.

Comment: This is fixed by this,.

select
    user_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(nickname) as nickname,
    GROUP_CONCAT(first_name) as first_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(last_name) as last_name 
 from (select
    wu.*,
    case when meta_key = "nickname" then meta_value end as nickname,
    case when meta_key = "first_name" then meta_value end as first_name,
    case when meta_key = "last_name" then meta_value end as last_name
  from user_table wu) x
  group by user_id
;

Comment: This is why I told you to read the considerations section as well. Btw, a max() may work better for you.